# Postgres - Get all clients and latest order

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a feeling I'll feel stupid when this is answered. I have a table of clients and a table of orders. I want a query that gives me a list of all clients, and their last order info if there is one, sorted by client name.

```
    SELECT c.id, c.name, o.order_time, o.item_name
    FROM clients AS c LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT client_id, max(order_time) AS order_time
        FROM orders GROUP BY client_id
    ) AS o
    ON(c.id = o.client_id)
    ORDER BY UPPER(c.name)"
```

My issue is I get the rows I want if I remove o.item_name but the query as written isn't valid because there's no way to get o.item_name without putting it in the GROUP BY. That, of course, causes it to return multiple rows per client. Hopefully my intent is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a window function:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, o.order_time, o.item_name
FROM clients AS c 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT client_id, 
           item_name,
           order_time,
           row_number() over (partition by client_id order by order_time desc) as rn
    FROM orders 
  ) AS o ON c.id = o.client_id and o.rn = 1
ORDER BY UPPER(c.name);
```

another option is to use Postgres' `distinct on()` operator which is usually faster than a solution using window functions:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, o.order_time, o.item_name
FROM clients AS c 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT distinct on (client_id) client_id, 
           item_name,
           order_time
    FROM orders 
    order by client_id, order_time desc
  ) AS o ON c.id = o.client_id 
ORDER BY UPPER(c.name);
```

Comment: On this second query where is `o.rn` defined?

Comment: Maybe it should be a limit 1 instead

Comment: @JorgeCampos: no, limit would be wrong as that would only return a single order, not one order per client_id

Comment: Still, how is the inner query filtering only the last order? I've already given +1 ! just curious!

Comment: @JorgeCampos: that's the `distinct on (client_id)` part - it only returns a single row per client_id

Comment: Great, new knowledge!! Thanks!!

Comment: I used your distinct on() solution, works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can use `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.name) c.id, c.name, o.order_time, o.item_name
FROM clients c LEFT JOIN
     orders o
    ON c.id = o.client_id
ORDER BY UPPER(c.name), o.order_time DESC;
```